# Add subdomain for port that listen node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, subdomain

Hi guys i have a problem. I work with php and node, php works with nginx listening port 80 and node works with the port 3000. I want add a subdomain that listen port 3000 a like media.mydomain.com but i could not. I tried with my website register domain and nothing happened and then with nginx in virtual host but show in console error because this port it is using.

nginx-php=mydomain.com

node=mydomain.com:3000  (tried add subdomain "media.fotogena.co")
virtual host:

```
 server {
     server_name media.mydomain.com;
     listen   mydomain.com:3000;
     #i don't know that do!
}#show error port is being used
```

and had seen something like upstream but this assign port 80 to port 3000 but don't is the that me need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand what you want to do, you want a subdomain to use instead of the port 3000, for the subdomain to work you need it to listen on port 80, and proxy what ever comes to port 3000.

```
server {
  server_name sub.example.com;
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: now works !!  :) but now show me a new problem :( I've changed in the script src "https://mydomain.com:3000" to "https://media.mydomain.com" and out for console the next: "WebSocket connection to 'wss://media.mydomain.com/socket.io/1/websocket/llM02Q4nDam4P4F0hoI1' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502 " i'm seraching in the web for a answer

Comment: the other script should work normally with the `domain.com:3000`, don't change it to port 80

Comment: i been read much docs and say that in nginx 1.4.7 works ok with the proxy websocket but now don't works the code that you written :( don't works

Comment: the point is you can't use nodejs on port 80, because you already have nginx listening to port 80, if nodejs takes port 80 then all your other subdomains won't work. if you want you can deny external access to port 3000 using iptables.